# Filtering input - is is_int enough

Tags: php

I am writing a controller action that takes two inputs from a form: an existing user id and and a new userid.

Both should be integer values.

To avoid any potential security problems, is it enough to simply check is_int?

ie:

```
if (is_int($existingUserId)) {

}
```

This should avoid any problems i think - but am not 100% sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) instead of `is_int`.

According to the [`is_int` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php): `is_int('23') = bool(false)`. Also, the documentation notes:

> To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric().

Comment: A cast to int would help in most cases as well and wouldn't hurt anyone.

Comment: @JordanDoyle A cast to int will simply convert non-numeric values into `0`, which may have unintended side effects.  I recommend the cast, but only after performing the numeric check.

Comment: Well that would help to catch out empty values and naughty strings and in most cases ids with autoincrease in MySQL are 1-indexed so an id should never be zero.

Comment: is_numeric makes sense.  Using that therefore, this will avoid all potential security problems related to form posting and user supplied input?

Comment: @MartyWallace For numeric inputs, yes.